# Is there any white water rafting nearby Bangalore, India?

Tags: water-sports, bangalore, rivers

I am living in Bangalore. I am looking for a one day outing nearby Bangalore. I am looking for water adventures like white water river rafting, kayaking , fishing. I found 3 to 4 in Karnataka like near Coorg, Sitanadi, Dandeli and Bheemeshwari. Which one gives a good option for a one day trip?

Comment: If there are rivers, there'll be rafting. Could you be more specific? Full-day/half day? What grade rapids? What's 'near' Bangalore - ie a day trip distance, or would you consider a weekend?

Comment: I am sorry @Mark for not following the rules, I hope the edited one is better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Mark said, you need to define what is near. Anyways, I am considering near as overnight drive.

The one I have been to is [Dandeli](http://www.dandeli.com/). It is one of the best river rafting destinations in South India. There are direct buses from Bangalore.

The rapids are really exciting and there are trained instructors as well, in case you are a newbie.

Comment: thanks for replying, Dandeli is a good place for long weekend.